# Unicode Error when make run server on Mattermost?

Tags: windows, unicode, server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mattermost

[image: error screenshot]
After following the instructions here: https://developers.mattermost.com/contribute/server/developer-setup/

I encountered another error: See attached image

UnicodeDecodeError

I'm new to docker and go, so I'm not sure what this implies. (Or could be the way I set up my windows?)

**Window [Version 10.0.19041.746]**

Anyone using Windows system and have experiences with Mattermost?

Github repo for mattermost: https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server

I've also posted the same question in the mattermost forum!

If anyone can point me in the right direction to trouble shoot the issues, I'll greatly appreciate it!